# Image resizing and resolution - change in image file, but nothing happens on site

Tags: html, caching, browser-cache

I am wondering if anybody else ever encounters this problem, and if there is something I'm not doing or missing in order to resolve it:

While building a site I am trying to resize my images so that they are all the same height.

I change all the image files to the same height and resolution in a photo-editing software, but yet when I replace the old images with the new image in the root folder, nothing changes when I preview it on the page. It's not a file naming/structure issue or anything like that, the right files are in the right folders, everything is correct there. When I open the html file in chrome and see that no change in the size is appearing I have tried clearing the cache, incognito windows, hard refreshes, reboots, waiting days to see if the magic internet gods change it ... but nothing works. The images remain in their original non-uniform sizes they were before. It's like the new image sizes/files are not being registered.

Has this ever happened to anyone else?

Comment: browser cache. cache on server. cache in between (CDN, proxy, ...). this is a web development question. -- tag the specific technologies you use. you're being extremely vague.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Photoshop doesn't have pages or incognito mode. It's not at all clear what you are referring to.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you for your reply, yes, I realize now I had the wrong tags. Sorry, I'm kind of new. I reworded my issues so that hopefully it is a bit more specific. Yes, I was thinking it must be a cache issue because the files I changed to are physically different sizes. I've obviously tried clearing my browsers cache, I haven't done so on my server's cache but could probably figure out how to do that, but what do you mean by 'cache in between' ?